# Utilizing std::map and std::array for displaying a modulus grid

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, stl

I've written a modulus-type program (using `std::vector`).  The user inputs a number, and the program displays a modulus grid pertaining to that number.

This is what it looks like (example program output with 12):

> ```
> (0)  12 24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108  120
> (1)  13  25  37  49  61  73  85  97  109  121
> (2)  14  26  38  50  62  74  86  98  110  122
> (3)  15  27  39  51  63  75  87  99  111  123
> (4)  16  28  40  52  64  76  88  100  112  124
> (5)  17  29  41  53  65  77  89  101  113  125
> (6)  18  30  42  54  66  78  90  102  114  126
> (7)  19  31  43  55  67  79  91  103  115  127
> (8)  20  32  44  56  68  80  92  104  116  128
> (9)  21  33  45  57  69  81  93  105  117  129
> (10)  22  34  46  58  70  82  94  106  118  130
> (11)  23  35  47  59  71  83  95  107  119  131
> (12)  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108  120  132
> ```

Now, I've decided to make it nicer by using `std::map` and `std::array`.  I get the same output as before, but with the same alignment issues (fixing those could complicate my display function).

Is this an effective use of these containers (and am I using them correctly)?  If not, what other containers could be used instead?  I'm using `std::array` instead of `std::vector` here because I'm keeping the number of columns (array size) at 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <array>

const unsigned NUM_ARR_ELEMS = 10;

std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>> getModGrid(unsigned);
void displayModGrid(const std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>>&);

int main()
{
    std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>> modGrid;
    unsigned mod;

    std::cout << "\n\n> Mod: ";
    std::cin >> mod;

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    modGrid = getModGrid(mod);
    displayModGrid(modGrid);

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}

std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>> getModGrid(unsigned mod)
{
    std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>> modRow;
    std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS> modValues;

    for (unsigned modIter = 0; modIter <= mod; ++modIter)
    {
        for (unsigned arrIter = 0; arrIter < NUM_ARR_ELEMS; ++arrIter)
            modValues[arrIter] = modIter + (mod * (arrIter+1));

        modRow[modIter] = modValues;
    }

    return modRow;
}

void displayModGrid(const std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>> &modGrid)
{
    for (auto rowIter = modGrid.cbegin(); rowIter != modGrid.cend(); ++rowIter)
    {
        std::cout << "  (" << rowIter->first << ")  ";

        for (auto colIter = rowIter->second.cbegin(); colIter != rowIter->second.cend(); ++colIter)
        {
            std::cout << *colIter << "  ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using a range-based for loop?

Comment: My compiler doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: How about using a vector of arrays instead of a map?

Comment: That's another option.  I went with `std::map` at first because the left-hand column works well as key values.  I'll try this out.

Comment: @VaughnCato, I got it working.  I even allowed the user to specify a number of columns (excluding the very first one).  Should I post that code under the original, in case it may need further analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through my code output and thinking about the comments, I've decided that a map of arrays isn't best.  I can see how a map can still display it in order (first column numbers as the keys), but that's about it.  It does make more sense to use a vector of vectors, after deciding that it's okay to let the user control the number of columns calculated and displayed.

Answer (score 2):

- `main()` can be defined lastly, so that the function prototypes can be removed.  This will also allow `NUM_ARR_ELEMS` to be initialized within `main()`.  The size of either the inner or outer structure can still be accessed via `size()`.
- For simple input like this, a command line argument is another option:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      unsigned int mod;

      // only argument being the file name
      if (argc < 2)
      {
          std::cin << mod;
      }
      // more than the file name, where only the second is used
      else
      {
          mod = std::atoi(argv[1]);
      }
  }
  ```

  **Warning:** `std::atoi()` returns an `int`, but `mod` is an `unsigned int`.  As this is a mismatch (and should be reported by the compiler), something else should be changed.  Either the return value of `std::atoi()` should be cast to an `unsigned int`, or `mod` should just be changed to an `int` (and adjusted elsewhere).  The latter may be a better option here, and the extra unsigned bit really isn't important.  Input validation (to avoid a negative value) can be done as well.
- This type is quite long to copy in different places:

  > ```
  > std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>>
  > ```

  so it can become a `typedef`:

  ```
  typedef std::map<unsigned, std::array<unsigned, NUM_ARR_ELEMS>> Grid;
  ```
- Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl` for just a newline.  The latter also flushes the buffer.